# Is this a bug with Advantage Database?

Tags: php, sql, advantage-database-server

I am running into what seems to me to be a bug in the Advantage Database PHP Extension (I know, I know...). I've reported it as a bug, but still haven't heard anything back, so I thought I'd run it by you guys.

**Working Code:**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    $connection = ads_connect( 'DataDirectory=\\some\path\;ServerTypes=2;RightsChecking=Off;TrimTrailingSpaces=true;CommType=TCP_IP;', '', '' );

    $results = ads_do( $connection , 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM projects');

    ads_close( $connection );
}
```

This just loops through 100 times, connects to the db, executes a query, and disconnects.

**NON-Working Code:**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    $connection = ads_connect( 'DataDirectory=\\some\path\;ServerTypes=2;RightsChecking=Off;TrimTrailingSpaces=true;CommType=TCP_IP;', '', '' );

    $results = ads_do( $connection , 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM projects');
    $results = ads_do( $connection , 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM projects');

    ads_close( $connection );
}
```

Notice the second query execution? This loop fails on the 51st cycle (the db server limits each application to 50 simultaneous connections) with the error

> Error 6303:  Maximum Advantage
>   Database Server connections exceeded.

I've tried several other things including this with no success:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    $connection = ads_connect( 'DataDirectory=\\some\path\;ServerTypes=2;RightsChecking=Off;TrimTrailingSpaces=true;CommType=TCP_IP;', '', '' );

    $results = ads_do( $connection , 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM projects');
    ads_free_result( $results );

    $results = ads_do( $connection , 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM projects');
    ads_free_result( $results );

    ads_close( $connection );
}
```

This, however, **DOES** fix the problem, and BOTH queries still execute successfully and accurately!!

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    $connection = ads_connect( 'DataDirectory=\\some\path\;ServerTypes=2;RightsChecking=Off;TrimTrailingSpaces=true;CommType=TCP_IP;', '', '' );

    $results = ads_do( $connection , 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM projects');
    ads_close( $connection );

    $results = ads_do( $connection , 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM projects');
    ads_close( $connection );   
}
```

This all seems very odd to me... any ideas?

**EDIT:** I am on PHP 5.2.5 and ADS 8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The knowledge base has this item on the 6303 error and how to increase the number of connections possible from a client, http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=17&RefNo=981124-0621.  R&D is currently looking into this problem and working to have it resolved in the next service release.

Comment: This shows what the error means, and how to allow more connections. It does not, however, explain why you get a max connections error when all connections are closed before reconnecting.

Comment: That would be the part R&D is looking at.  It appears to be a problem with reference counting when multiple statements our open on a connection.

Comment: R&D has confirmed this is a bug with the reference counting of connections with multiple statements open.  It will be fixed in the next service release.